# nosql data duplicate and performance?

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

Suppose user A sent contact request to user B, so in user A's document looks like this:

```
send_request=
{
    contact:[{
        id:A,
        to:B,
        status:'pending',
        seen:0
    }]
}
```

and in user B's document looks like this:

```
recieved_request=
{
    contact:[{
        id:B,
        from:A,
        status:'pending',
        seen:0
    }]
}
```

It will be updated both document whenever user B respond(accept or reject) or seen once.

My question is if is it good approach to insert/update same data on both documents? I found that the benefit is on reading would be faster i.e. whenever user B logged in, the system only need to query user B's document to get all details, no need to ref other document.

If it's a bad approach, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

What is good for one scenario is bad for another one. Even in the same program.

Indexes, for example. Very-very good for querying, but slow down updates.

Same here, you simplify/accelerate your queries, but complicate writes and introduce potential for data desynchronization. If you can live with these (and other drawbacks, like increased storage requirements), then it's a "good" approach.